# Drush does not download modules correctly

Tags: drush

Drush says it downloads a module successfully but instead of putting it in sites/all/modules it puts it in the current directory:
$ drush dl module_filter
Project module_filter (7.x-2.0-alpha2) downloaded to                 [success]
/drupal/module_filter.
The folder doesn't exist, but if you run the command again the following happens:
$ drush dl module_filter
Install location drupal/module_filter already exists. Do you want to overwrite it? (y/n):

drush version 7.x

Comment: Perhaps drush isn't able to connect with the drupal db correctly. Sometimes, I've found that drush works better if the db_host is set to 127.0.0.1, rather than localhost in settings.php.

Answer (score 2):

Drush will put downloaded modules in the current directory if it cannot bootstrap a Drupal site.  Run `drush status` to determine whether or not the Drupal site you think you are operating on is recognized by Drush.  You might need to use the --uri option to specify the name of the folder that contains the settings.php file, or set up a Drush alias file.

Comment: Hmm running drush status --uri=sites/default shows php and drush version. It does not show the regular drupal instances.
Further drush dl drupal should work anywhere I would assume, but I get the same behavior.

Comment: You do not need --uri if settings.php is in the default folder.  If settings.php is in sites/foo.com, then use --uri=foo.com.  You must also tell Drush where your Drupal root is.  `cd /path/to/drupalroot/` or `drush --root=/path/to/drupalroot`.  Read the README and the beginning of http://definitivedrupal.org/book/26-drush (sample chapter for book, available for free download).

Comment: Why is it creating psuedo modules though the modules don't actually show up in the filesystem? I had previously had drush working and it just stopped. There is a default/settings.php with a valid db hooked up. I find also that I can correctly download modules if I have not enabled xampp. However I cannot run any commands like drush en or drush hlp. I also set up an alias like the chapter mentioned and it returns the same result. If I visit the virtual host I get the site so I know it's a valid directory.